# how to show the JSON multidimensional array of output on a kendo grid.?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Sharon",
        "last_name": "Allen",
        "hired": "George",
        "email": "gallen0@addtoany.com",
        "location": "Ukraine",
        "groups": "Chynadiyovo",
        "roles": [{"role1":"TEST1" },{"role2":"Test2"},{"role3":"Test3"}]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Carl",
        "last_name": "Kelley",
        "hired": "Michael",
        "email": "mkelley1@hubpages.com",
        "location": "Russia",
        "groups": "Proletarskiy",
        "roles": [{"role1":"TEST1" },{"role2":"Test2"},{"role3":"Test3"}]
    }
]
```

[image]

For the roles i am getting output as [object Object]

```
    angular.module('xenon.controllers').controller('membersctrl', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, $cookies, $timeout, memberssrvc) {

        memberssrvc.getMembers().success(function (MembersData) {
        //console.log(MembersData);
        console.log(MembersData[0].roles[0]);
            $(angular.element(document.querySelector('#grid'))).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: MembersData,
                     schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                id: { type: "number" },
                                first_name: { type: "string" },
                                last_name: { type: "string" },
                                hired: { type: "string" },
                                email: { type: "string" },
                                location: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                height: 500,
                columns: [
                                { field:"first_name", title: "First Name" },
                                { field: "last_name", title:"Last Name" },
                                { field: "hired", title:"Hired"},
                                { field: "email",title:"Email"},
                                { field: "roles",title:"Roles"},
                                {  hidden: true,  field: "location",title:"Location"},
                                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                                editable: "popup",
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                batch: true,

                selectable: "multiple",
                filterable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                resizable: true,
                EnableAlternatingRowColor: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5


   }
        }).error(function () {

        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **[column template](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)** to create a list of roles as a string.

```
{ 
    field: "roles",
    title:"Roles",
    template: "#for(var i=0;i<roles.length;i++) { if (i > 0) {#,# }# #: roles[i]['role' + (i + 1)]##}#"
},
```

The template iterates through the roles and builds a comma delimited list of the roles (e.g. "TEST1, Test2, Test3")

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OxoSE)**

Image :

[image]

Comment: can we group roles? Thanks

Comment: @user2092317, did you look at the demo i linked? See this: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ofeZI

Comment: i have looked at the link. but when i try to drag and drop the role in the to group them. the grid is getting stuck

Comment: @user2092317, i misunderstood. i thought you wanted the list of roles within the column grouped...

Comment: @user2092317, you could pre-process the data to create a string field instead of object field:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ofeZI

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have been given an answer but I personally prefer either one of these two ways myself:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EKesu (using @ezanker as a template for mine)

1) **Pure Javascript Version**

rather than using the `inline` javascript version given above which can get clunky and a nightmare to debug when you get complex templates

so changing the template declaration to this:

```
template: "#=showRoles(data.roles) #"
```

then using this javascript function:

```
      function showRoles(roles){
        var retString = ''; 

        if(roles !== null && roles.length > 0)
        {
          retString = '<ul>'; 
          var index = 1; 

          roles.forEach(function(item){
            retString += '<li>' + item["role"+ index] + '</li>';
            index++;
          });

          retString += '</ul>'; 


        }
        else 
        {
          retString = '<span>-</span>';
        }

        return retString; 

      }
```

all this does is cycle through the collection and then creates a list for you. if no list is present a default string is shown.

2) **Kendo Template**

The second version of the column uses a similar setup i.e.:

```
 template: "#= getByTemplate(data.roles) #"
```

but rather than building the html in javascript we use the templating engine within kendo. So we first build the template:

```
  <script id="rolesTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

          <ul>
          #for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){#

          <li> role: #=data[i]["role" + (i + 1)]#</li>

          #}#
          </ul>

  </script>
```

then using this javascript function:

```
   function getByTemplate(data){
      var rolestemplate = $("#rolesTemplate").html();
      var template = kendo.template(rolestemplate);
      return template(data); 
   }
```

This reads in the template and then passing the roles collection in then executes it and passes back the generated html to present to the screen.

I personally prefer the first option but for large complex html structures the kendo templating keeps things easy to read especially if you have a lot of buttons you want have within a group or as a dropdown.

Use which ever you feel most comfortable using and go with that.

Comment: I agree that you have presented more maintainable code and that the OP should go with these options. +1. I was taking the quick route to show that column templates could be used to solve this problem.

Comment: I think your solution is more than fine for really simple things but as I said with larger complex things like using `bootstrap button groups` or even popovers i found with inlining the javascript I would always miss a hash out somewhere and then spend ages trying to figure it out.

Comment: can we group roles? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can group by roles but you will have to perform the grouping server side as the client side may not work as expected. Also depends on how you plan to do the grouping.